# Where exactly is the "metadata" boundary in a JPEG raw blob?

Tags: java, javascript, c, image, jpeg

I understand there are many types of "metadata" in a JPEG image:

http://fotoforensics.com/tutorial-meta.php

but where would I have to cut the byte array to split the blob into a general metadata part and the remaining actual image data part?

I want to preserve **all** metadata, resize the image, and then add the previously stored metadata again.

What's the magic separator byte sequence or position or something?

thanks

Comment: What has this to do with JavaScript?

Comment: Actually I want to do this in JavaScript (on Blob types), but I figured more low level language audiences are probably more experienced in byte level manipulations of files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is "it depends..." :)

There are several things to consider here:

1. Strictly speaking, "jpeg" is the encoding of the actual image data, and does not specify the file format as I believe you want it.  The common file formats are either JFIF or Exif, each allowing for different types of metadata
2. The JFIF and Exif file formats don't have a complete, hard boundary between metadata and image data.  JFIF files, for instance, are made up of many segments; almost all of these are followed by some amount of data.  Exif is more complicated, but follows the same principle.  As an example, there are several tags defined as APP0...APPn.  Many programs/companies use these segments to encode some form of metadata.  After each segment marker is two-byte length field, followed by up to 64K of data (as bounded by two bytes of the length field).
3. There can be any number of these fields used to specify metadata
4. These fields can technically occur anywhere in the file, although they are usually only found before the "image data"
5. The term "image data" is very loose.  What I believe you mean by "image data" is actually spread across many different types of segments as well.  As a simple example, there are Huffman encoding table segments (beginning with a segment marker 0xFFC4), and actual scan data segments (beginning with a segment marker 0xFFDA).  I think that there a strong case to make that these segments are both considered to be "image data"

I'm far from an expert on these formats, but unfortunately I think the answer is much more complex than you were hoping.  If you want to read all of the non-image data information, you really will need to parse the entire image file.  The good news is that I'm sure there have to be libraries to do this (although I don't know about JS libs).

This is grossly over-simplified, but it's just meant to give you an idea of what you need to look into

**-Edit- Some references:**

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/JPEG_-_Idea_and_Practice/The_header_part

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG#JPEG_files

[The actual JFIF file spec](http://www.w3.org/Graphics/JPEG/jfif3.pdf)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchangeable_image_file_format

[The actual Exif file spec](http://www.exiv2.org/Exif2-2.PDF)

Comment: Thanks, this is great information! Too bad it is far more complex than I hoped.. I guess I will simply extract the Exif metadata then (already doing that) and call it a day :/

Comment: One follow up question: can Exif (JFIF) encoded JPEG files also contain, non-Exif (non-JFIF) metadata at the same time? Or is it a fair assumption that an Exif or JFIF file contains either Exif stuff or JFIF stuff and nothing else.

Comment: @user3280015 Yes.  I have less experience with the more complex Exif format, but I believe that the Exif metadata itself is actually specified behind an APP1 segment marker at the beginning of the image.  If you want to add any arbitrary information, you can do so by simply inserting it after any APPx segment marker that you create.  Just make sure to get the length field right, and you should be able to add any amount of data across any number of APPx segments

Answer (score 0):

I respond to clear up some things. The JPEG standard is unimplementable. For example, it defines how to encode and decode components but does not define what a component it. JFIF was the first JPEG file format in common use to fill in the gaps.

If we define metadata to be all the descriptive data not required to decode the compressed image; there is a fairly clear boundary between data and metadata. For the most part any APPn or COM marker is metadata.

I say for the most part because the mere existence of a JFIF APP0 marker tells the decoder that the image is either grayscale or in YCbCr format, uncorrected for gamma. There is actually very little metadata in JFIF (thumbnail, pixel density).

The structure of JFIF and and EXIF stream differs only in the format of the APPn markers that define the formats. Since the APPn marker includes a length, a decoder can skip over the marker without reading any of the metadata. In other words, a JPEG decoder only really needs to know that it encountered a JFIF APP0 marker or EXIF APP1 marker to decode the image and does not need to read the data within those marker.

The greater complexity of EXIF over JFIF occurs only in the APPn markers. Again, a decoder can ignore that complexity by simply skipping over the marker.

JFIF requires the stream to begin with an SOI marker followed by an APP1 JFIF marker. After that, you can include whatever APPn or COM markers you want in any order. The only restriction is the marker data cannot begin with JFIF or JFXX.

There is nothing in the JFIF APP0 marker that is linked to the compressed data. This is NOT true with EXIF. You can encode the image size in the APP1 marker that is also encoded in the SOF marker. I don't know what would happen if those values a different. A decoder would probably use the values in the SOF marker and ignore those in the APP1 marker. Some applications may not like different values, however.

The structure of a JPEG stream at the marker level is very simple. The EXIF header is overly complicated.